# Can not find User.Identity.GetUserId() Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Using Visual Studio 2013 Express MVC application with references to
MVC 5.2
Asp.Net.Identity.Core 2.0

inside any controller or from anywhere else in my application the method GetUserId() does not seem to exist and I can not for the life of my understand how that could be. I was under the impression it was a method included in Asp.Net Identity 2x. What might I be missing here?

Comment: Have you added the namespace `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` ?

Comment: There it is... wow.. Since I could access User.Identity.Name and IsAuthenticated without adding that namespace.. I assumed it was just available... Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it is a bit tricky because User.Identity is available . If you goto(f12) on `GetUserId()` you will see that it is in a group for IdentityExtensions . Which is neat because it is a little template to create your own extensions using [System.Security.Principal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49455251/3400042) this solved the problem for me

Answer (score 36):

It is an extension method. Reference the name space at the top of the class.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since 2015 RC1 the GetUserId extension method is in the System.Security.Claims namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can get userId with ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier

```
var userId =  User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
```

Of course we have to add using at the top.

```
using System.Security.Claims;
```